# How can I unpack a .deb on Mac OS X without installing it? 

Tags: macos

I have a .deb file that I want to unpack and examine, but not install. I'm currently looking for where i can download dpkg for OSX, but can't find it. If you have a link, please share.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

`ar` is already installed on my mac on OS X. So just do

```
ar -x path/to/deb/file.deb
```

that's it. No need to install other software.

Comment: Users of XCode 4 can run `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ar`.

Comment: @zpletan Why not `/usr/bin/ar` ?

Comment: `ar` comes from XCode (unless you installed it with MacPorts/Homebrew/etc), but XCode 4 comes from the App Store and therefore doesn't install anything in /usr/bin by default. I think you can change it from preferences, but that's the default.

Comment: @zpletan I've never installed anything in `/usr/bin`, so `ar` must be from the default installation. (Unless I am totally mistaken.)

Comment: @zpletan I've just checked: `/usr/bin/ar` is installed via the package `DeveloperToolsCLI`, which is probably an optional install (but I wonder where I chose to install these tools)

Comment: All I know is, I followed the Internet's instructions to uninstall v3 and then installed v4, and now I can only get to it via the path I posted. Like I said, I think there is an optional install in prefs that puts all XCode's stuff in /usr/bin, but it's optional.

Comment: This doesn’t generally work. I’ve got a `.deb` file that unpacks beautifully with `dpkg` but `ar` fails because it thinks the package contains a different set of folders, with different names, than it actually contains.

Answer (score 4):

You can [install dpkg using MacPorts](http://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/sysutils/dpkg/Portfile) or just [download the sources](http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.14.29.tar.gz).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is actually the method I used.

Answer (score 4):

While not OSX specific, if you have Docker for Mac installed, you could use an Ubuntu container to look inside the contents of the package:

```
docker run -it -v $(pwd):/data ubuntu:latest /bin/bash
dpkg -c /data/foo.deb
```

Comment: got a typo in spelling ubuntu though. But I have used your solution.

Answer (score 1):

if you use [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) you can install dpkg and more package (like do it in debian or ubuntu).

after installing Macports go and install [dpkg from here](https://ports.macports.org/port/dpkg/).

also you can find more info about dpkg in osx [here](https://www.osxfaq.com/man/1/dpkg-deb.ws). (This is now down - I don't know if temporarily or permanently)

Comment: @Thomas, MacPorts, formerly called DarwinPorts

Comment: DarwinPorts.com is a rip off of MacPorts.org. MacPorts.org used to be at DarwinPorts.org - see http://trac.macports.org/wiki/DarwinPortsFraud

Answer (score 1):

At least on recent macOS versions, you can also use `tar` to extract UNIX archives:

```
tar xf package.deb
```

Comment: Yes but is dpkg a Unix archive?

Answer (score 0):

```
brew install dpkg
dpkg -c file.deb # This will give you contents list
dpkg -x file.deb # This will extract
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. If you can explain how this is better than the accepted answer to use a built in command like `ar` [please consider making an edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/467167/edit) to elaborate.

Answer (score -1):

```bsh
docker run -it -v $(pwd):/data ubuntu:latest /bin/bash
# or with fish
# docker run -it -v (pwd):/data ubuntu:latest /bin/bash
cd data
dpkg -x wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.focal_amd64.deb out
ls out/usr/local/bin/
```

works well for wkhtmltoimage and wkhtmltopdf

Comment: This is the same as https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/418659/237 or if extra information it should be an edit to that

Comment: @mmmmmm it's `dpkg -x` not `dpkg -c`

Comment: Then I think it would make sense to describe why it is different and the benefit. People shouldn't be copying code without understanding it so an explanation should always be given